# how to send a message with ibeacon swift?

Tags: swift, bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm working with speed 4 beacons.

I send beacon with device1, with device2 I receive this beacon

device2 must send a message to the device1, device2 knows uid, region, major, minor of device1.

How to send a message to device1 from the device2?

I do not want to use api nearby of google.

Comment: iBeacons don't send messages, they just let you know that they're nearby.

Comment: Are you trying to get beacon to beacon communication? If you can just change the major minor values of your own advertisements you can make a simple messaging system

Comment: @Sirens  What I want to do is:
when device2 finds beacons, that is, many devices, to each one send a message, for example "hello, welcome to my world", this message should be an alert, not a notification.
The devices that receive the message, just give an ok or cancel, and that's it.

until now my development is:
Device2 finds the other devices, and I know of each one the data of your ibeacon, how do I send that alert to all the found devices? the devices that receive the message do not have to send a reply, they just receive the message and that's it.

Comment: You’ll have to do some fancy encoding like I said. Use the major minor values to encode messages and then send the beacons in a specific order.